# log4j-core it's not present on classpath with spring-boot-starter-log4j2

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, spring-boot

I configured my spring boot application according this -> http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging

But when the application start, appear the message:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. 
Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console.
```

It's weird because when I compile the uber jar it's possible to see the `log4j` jar embedded. And if I put the dependencies of `lo4j2` manually the application works.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyzzzz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>xxxx</name>
    <description>xxx</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I researched in many blog posts or here on stackoverflow and I didn't find similar problem. Something it's wrong on my pom.xml? Or some idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just...keep the dependencies?  If it works with them in, why not just roll with that?

Comment: run `mvn dependency:tree`, do you see transitive dependecy of log4j-core?

Comment: How are you running the application, mvn spring-boot:run, java -jar, IDE?  Those dependencies are included with the log4j2 starter so that's definitely weird: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-log4j2/pom.xml#L26-L33

Comment: @Makoto I wrote to check if it's a bug or if the problem is my project. Because should be work according the documentation.

Comment: @J-Alex yes the log4j exist:
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:1.5.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.7:compile

Comment: @punkrocker27ka the problem occurred with the mvn or java -jar
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ xyz ---
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...